# How to create dynamically buttons in py file and inject to kivy file

Tags: python, kivy

I know it might be silly question, but im struggling with making dynamically some buttons/labels in my PageLayout.
I can make it work in my py file but i dont want to mess my files and try keep it more clear.

In below code im making screen with Gridlayout in which i put pagelayout in which ill create as many buttons/labels as many values ill have in my list which ill make later(for now i use for loop just to make sure everything works with my app) and gridlayout with 2 buttons.

```
class LoginSuccesfull(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LoginSuccesfull, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        main_grid = GridLayout(cols=1)
        layout = PageLayout()
        grid = GridLayout(cols=2)
        self.add_widget(main_grid)

        main_grid.add_widget(layout)
        main_grid.add_widget(grid)
        label = Button(text='left')
        label2 = Button(text='right')
        grid.add_widget(label)
        grid.add_widget(label2)

        for i in range (8):
            layout.add_widget(Button(text='test'))

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()
```

kv file

```
<LoginSuccesfull>:

<RootWidget>:
    LoginScreen:
        name:'login_screen'
    SignUpScreen:
        name:'sign_up'

    LoginSuccesfull:
        name:'login_succesfull'
```

I would like to make it to look more like this, but i have no clue how to achieve this(im still new to kivy and python) so my py file stays more clear.

```
<LoginSuccesfull>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        PageLayout:
                    <<<< Create buttons in py file

        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Button:
                text:'left'
            Button:
                text:'right'
```

I just dont know how to refer only to PageLayout to make buttons/labels. Any help would be appreciated.